# How many functions Injective have for $|A|=3 \rightarrow |B|=4$ And How many Surjective

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many functions Injective and Surjective have for $|A|=3 \rightarrow |B|=4$
for example :
$$A=\{1,2,3\} \rightarrow B=\{1,2,3,4\}$$
the answer for Injective is: $4\cdot 3 \cdot 2$ or $\binom {3} {4}$
for how many surjective functions we have I didnt understand that because $A$ dont point on all the elements in $B$

any suggestions?
thanks!

**EDIT**
if I want all the functions from $|A|=3 \rightarrow |B|=4$ so  how many functions I have now?

Comment: **Hint:** the number of surjections is the easiest part.

Comment: $3\choose 4$ is not correct (but $4\cdot 3\cdot 2$ is)

Comment: why not? I`m selecting 3 from 4

Comment: @GitGud its cant be surjective?

Comment: see Additional info in my answer for your related question, you just asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|A|=3$ and $|B|=4$, then you have $4^3 = 64$ possible functions from $A$ to $B$. Of those you have $3!\cdot \binom{4}{3} = 24$ injective ones (notice that we use the binomial to choose $3$ elements from $B$, and then we count the permutations of $A$ with the factorial to find the possible different assignments). Since $|B|>|A|$, there are no surjective functions $A\rightarrow B$.

Comment: $4\cdot 3 \cdot 2$ its fine too but I want to understand $3!\cdot \binom {4}{3}$

Comment: @OfirAttia As I have already written in the answer, $\binom{4}{3}$ means "choose $3$ elements out of the $4$ of $B$", then the $3!$ counts the ways you can assign them to the elements of $A$. You can see this as: you have $3$ boxes (the elements of $A$) and $3$ different balls (the $3$ elements of $B$ you have chosen), how many ways are there to put the three balls in the three boxes, one ball for every box?

Comment: 3 options for each ball

Comment: @OfirAttia No, the first ball has $3$ options, the second one is left with $2$, and the third with only $1$, whence $3\cdot 2\cdot 1=3!$.

Comment: Ah right, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $4>3$.

> If $X\to Y$ is surjective, then clearly $|Y|\le|X|$.